# Conflict between OnRowDataBound and OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, backcolor

I have a Gridview that is colored on OnRowDataBound event according to a #Colorcode taken from an not visible Cell in the Grid. That works perfectly!

But once you select a row, the coloring is lost and the selected row is NOT highlighted anymore, as it did before I added the OnRowDataBound event. In order to get the rows colored again I do a DataBind() on the GridView; to highlight the selected row I manually set the Backcolor. This works for the colored rows, but does not highlight the selected row.

How do I achieve that the selected row is highlighted?
Martin

```
protected void DisplayName_onselectedindexchanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row1 = GridView02.SelectedRow;
    FormView02.Visible = true;
    GridView02.DataBind();
    row1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#FFFF80");          
}


protected void PaintRows_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string getValue = (e.Row.FindControl("Colorcode") as Label).Text;
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(getValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could skip all of this logic and just use the [SelectedRowStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFFF80" />
```

Your problem is that you are re-binding your GridView in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. If you remove that, it should work just fine.

Comment: 1) The <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFFF80" /> command stopped working after I added the OnRowDataBound event where I assign the BackColor to the rows. 2) I needed to re-bind because selecting a row would make me loose all the row colors

Comment: So if you keep everything the way you have posted, just remove the `GridView02.DataBind();` line, it does not work? If so, my guess is that you are binding again somewhere else that I cannot see. I tested it out and it works just fine for me.

Comment: There is no other bind I'm calling! So it worked for you? With the coloring of the rows and the highlighted selected row?

Comment: Yes, both ways described in my answer above work perfectly for me. I color every row green in `RowDataBound` and I color the selected row red in `SelectedIndexChanged`.

Comment: One thing that may need to be looked at though is that you are calling the correct event handlers. I see `DisplayName_onselectedindexchanged` and `PaintRows_OnRowDataBound`. Are "DisplayName" and "PaintRows" two different GridViews? Or are they handlers for the same GridView (`GridView02`), just named something different?

Comment: The belong to the same Gridview02... thank you for the interest!

Comment: I changed the Background argument from dynamic to a static green, as you did yesterday and it actually does what you said. The rows are colored and the selected row is highlighted. BUT - and please confirm that this applies to you too - changing the selection will leave the prior selected row in default color and NOT in green. So one has to take care of this too by saving the rows position and coloring it once you switch to another row. But this can be handled. More annoying is, that I can't use the dynamic calculated value based on the content of a cell. Do you have any idea what causes this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, that does not happen for me. Even with dynamic colors, it still works as expected. What do you mean by default color though? Is the default not green? You said green was static.

Comment: Everything solved. Bad me! I used the wrong command to color the rows. Changing System.Drawing.Color.FromName(getValue) to System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(getValue) was the solution. This non consistent behavior must have been due to this.

Comment: Oh OK, I see. Glad you were able to figure it out!